# Broken type inference when extending recursive generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, recursive-type

I am in the following situation:

```
interface Rec {
  key: string;
  children: this[];
}
type Recursive<D extends string> = {
  [K in D]: string;
} & Rec;

type FlattenRecursive = 
  <D extends string, R extends Recursive<D>>(rs: R[]) => Omit<R, "children">[] 

const flatten: FlattenRecursive = 
  rs => rs.flatMap(r => flatten(r.children))
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&ts=4.7.0-dev.20220408#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQcg3gKGcgawgE8AuZAZzClAHMBuPZBAC2ABsATKCEcsNhQDaAXUYBfHGGIAHFOgQBXKBWAA3CAB4AIsggAPSCE4VK1OgD5kAXmxMhAaWShk2keSo0QDHOOQAyNAxGKVkUADF2ODAjBWVVDRtkJh09Q14TMy9aABo0NKNMuJV1LW0LCwAKFXJUUQBKGysAeQBbYDBNVDyAIlYObl4ei1FknAQAexAqZBgomN5ySOjYjHjSpKYVJuQVADo56IBZOBlqncOFkGq9-q4eEHr6nCA)

I expect the recursive call to the `flatten` function to be inferred as `flatten<D, R>` instead of the current `<string, R>`. Therefore, I'm forced to explicitly annotate the type arguments when calling it:

```
type RValueAnimal = Recursive<"value"> & { animal: string }

const rvalues: RValueAnimal[] = [
  // ...
]

flatten(rvalues) // <- error
flatten<"value", RValueAnimal>(rvalues)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&ts=4.6.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQcg3gKGcgawgE8AuZAZzClAHMBuPZBAC2ABsATKCEcsNhQDaAXUYBfHGGIAHFOgQBXKBWAA3CAB4AIsggAPSCE4VK1OgD5kAXmxMhAaWShk2keSo0QDHOOQAyNAxGKVkUADF2ODAjBWVVDRtkJh09Q14TMy9aABo0NKNMuJV1LW0LCwAKFXJUUQBKGysAeQBbYDBNVDyAIlYObl4ei1FknAQAexAqZBgomN5ySOjYjHjSpKYVJuQVADo56IBZOBlqncOFkGq9-q4eEHr6nBfpOTQANTh2RQgAQRAwFa3ySxQSWh6am+v2GAWwyDggOB7A85m8yEk4ymMygUJ+EAotS++IBQO+o1sQiYuHw+CIZGQPU8dAAjD0ckx8HjfuRIWyObSEUjvry4PzOcw2PdFshRExxAK7IL6bzmd4AEzsiXciC8tSaxX4RFklGMuAGiV3QZ8WUieWKmm0lWMtW0ADMWsFOr1HsNQpNot9lql1vIVMF+EdEcIJFVaNoABZPdHkN7GWok37BcbkaLMxLBVaHmG7dGFRLSxiOXacJcjNUdRRnnXeJpIdCIOzPh3SciqriO02gA)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Generic constraints do not serve as inference sites for other type parameters (this was suggested at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234 but never implemented) so `D` cannot be inferred from `R`; instead it falls back to `string`.  You should remove `D` entirely and refactor to express the constraint you care about purely in terms of `R`.  Maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGP4ow)?  Does that address your question fully? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, in fact I do not need to specify `D`. I think I could write `R extends Recursive<any>` or `R extends Recursive<never>`given that `D` seems to be contravariant (side question: I am not sure why it is not invariant given its recursive use).

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance, maybe later this evening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function type like

```
<D extends string, R extends Recursive<D>>(rs: R[]) => Omit<R, "children">[]
```

is that there is no *inference site* for the type parameter `D`.  You might hope that the compiler would be able to infer `D` using the [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) of `Recursive<D>` for the type parameter `R`.  Unfortunately, generic constraints do not serve as inference sites for other type parameters.  There was a suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234) to do this, but it was never implemented.

That means when you call such a function, inference will fail for `D`.  It will therefore fall back to its own constraint of `string`, and then `R` will be constrained to `Recursive<string>`, which breaks things.

---

My suggestion is to remove `D` entirely, and express the constraint you care about purely in terms of `R`.  For example:

```
type FlattenRecursive =
  <R extends Recursive<Extract<Exclude<keyof R, keyof Rec>, string>>>(
    rs: R[]) => Omit<R, "children">[]
```

This is a bit convoluted, but the idea is that what you were calling `D` can be computed from `keyof R` (it should be just those `string` keys of `R` which are not also keys of `Rec`).  And you can use it as desired:

```
flatten(rvalues); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&ts=4.6.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQcg3gKGcgawgE8AuZAZzClAHMBuPZBAC2ABsATKCEcsNhQDaAXUYBfHGGIAHFOgQBXKBWAA3CAB4AIsggAPSCE4VK1OgD5kAXmxMhAaWShk2keSo0QDHOOQAyNAxGKVkUADF2ODAjBWVVDRsmTVQ9Q14TIKUVdS0AUUMoRDBNAoR2RU4tImIAexg0ABpCEnqsi2bPSwsLAAomfBVyVFEAShsrAHkAW2AS1GaAIlYObl5Fi1EcHARakCpkGCiY3nJI6NiMeNykwdNrKxUAOiPogFk4GV6oCcPjo2+TxWXB4IFGo22oTkaAAanAKhAAIIgYDTeE2LLXDSaRZqeGKCAbALYZBwFFo9geczeZCSHZ7A5QPEIijDOEI5Go+GiDFCJi4fD4GrkRZdbwARkWjQGyGZBJFakl0sFpPJ8JFcCVMuBaz4yC2+HEyrsKuFyFF1NoACYpTK5RAFTbjfgyVzKea4E7tWwQad9SImEb+TKzRavLQAMy2lX2hVR52qt0a+Pe1ag8h8lX4AVZoUkEVi2gAFmjudl+Id5rUJYTKtdFI1NZlKp16f9zdpCYDhulAZwrxOIG+9ooo3oyAA9BPkLUCHBiDggA)