# How to type a record of generic interfaces with related constraints?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

I'm using a parser toolkit (Chevrotain) to write a query language, and would like to allow users to expand its functionality. I have all the pieces I need to do this, but am struggling with defining types for this expansion behavior. I'd like to be able to type the config object such that users using Typescript will have convenient IDE assistance asserting that their input is correct; it seems possible (or very close to possible), so I've been trying to write the types (rather than assert at runtime).

A (trivial) example of some config:

```js
ops: {
  equal: {
    lhs: {
      type: 'string',
      from: v => String(v),
    },
    rhs: {
      type: 'number',
      from: v => v.toString(),
    },
    compare: (lhs, rhs) => lhs === rhs,
  }
  equal: { /*...*/ }
}
```

I'd like the following things to be true:

1. The type of the argument to `from` is related to the string literal value of the `type` property. I've managed to accomplish this a few ways, the cleanest of which is a simple type such as:

```
type ArgTypes = {
  string: string,
  number: number,
  ref: any, // the strings don't have to be typescript types, and the types could be more complex
}
```

2. The `lhs` and `rhs` fields may receive different types than each other, and produce different types than each other.
3. The `compare` function takes as input the *output* of the `lhs` and `rhs` properties and returns a boolean.

I've been able to type things at the level of a single operator (`equal`), but I haven't been able to extend this into an object-bag of operators. Here's one Playground link where I tried to build it up a piece at a time, using generics and child types: [attempt N](https://tsplay.dev/WKOVzW). In this attempt, I can't seem to hold on to the narrow types once I get to the object-map bit; it might not be possible to have a type signature for `Ops` at line 105 that works?

And another (inspired by [Preventing object literals type widening when passed as argument in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73336911/preventing-object-literals-type-widening-when-passed-as-argument-in-typescript)) where I tried to do it all at once, just adding type arguments for every damn thing: [attempt N+1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwCrggZygXigbwFBSFQD0xUcEAZgFxQCGAdiANwFEBGA9pwDYSO0uvfg1ZEoaYHACWDBLUky5YogwCuAW3YQ4tdVp2sAvq1CQoAMTicNAGWnAAPEigQAHsAgMAJhgDWECCclLCIKJBoAHxYocioaADaSAC6pqhQAMI2YHQUjrYANFAAStHYABQ8ABZotIXkNbTFAJRY0UJ8jKyUagwAxsDSnAxQPf2ObIQu7p4%20GMUQfZxw3o6KsghFAMqQfZEFk1A7i64eXr64h%20LVtZfi90RmEHUAEvbABw8PlNYatOUANzoPFe4QgrUw0VsLwWwCuRCMny%20cEady%204ieTTeDiR6MIPxs-yBIJKLzBEOixRhEDh6MR8MIpCgSw0OQo-xuoNQRRRtyp5LaUA6IkO9PE0Pep1mFwCQRC8DiEVxpMlM3O-kCwViYLQyuhYKl6ssv3e%20WxwH2h356TVc2NNlNVPelvF1OAhrtjBAyqpsI9Fy9B0igOBameUCQzVoLhwUEOFGAajgI2JYeMrDwSwYklcVRiYz65XwGPQwFoxa%20nLReKgmKgAHJ1nJ68r0QS-lAAYKtlINoDmgyoGLkaiKzW6-X9No4C3B%20J27Qu5DOwA6YCcHtKBDlAd00UHIzNVhAA). This almost works, but the moment you uncomment the "compare" line in the type signature, the (previously-working) narrow types become general. (e.g. the literal `"number"` becomes `string`)

Is it possible to do this or should I give up? If so, how?

Comment: There's quite a bit going on in this code; can we simplify it?  Do you really need `T extends ArgTypes[K]` for example?  Is `ArgTypes[K]` not sufficient?  Even if it's not sufficient for your actual use case, is it sufficient to demonstrate the inference problem you're facing?  Right now I'm looking at what seems like six type aliases, some of which have six generic type parameters, and it's a bit much to process.  Maybe I can come back and look later, but it would be nicer if we could pare this down to a more *minimal* [mre] first.

Comment: My guess, from looking at this, is that you're never going to get *both* the generic type inference *and* the contextual type inference of the callback parameters (that is, `v` and `lhs` and `rhs`).  It's just too much simultaneous inference to be possible.  Would you be okay with building up your object by using the `args()` helper function inside the properties?  Like `const myOps = {equal: args(...), otherThing: args(...)}`? That is at least *possible*, even if you would prefer not to use it.

Comment: @jcalz I've tried dozens of variations of this code, these examples just happen to be close to the clearest versions I had to share at the moment. In the first link, at the top, are the simplified interfaces and you can see that they work in the _simple_ form; the problem comes when trying to combine it all together into the full thing. I have been unable to create a simpler working example that demonstrates my difficulty, since the difficulty is at this topmost level :\ (1/2)

Comment: My conclusion at the moment is to modify the interface -- something like a builder pattern: `opts().addOp(...).addOp(...)`. I have to keep reminding myself that I don't need a final type that represents all this -- I'm just trying to provide an ergonomic _user_-facing way to set things up. That's what I'll go with if I don't find an answer, but I don't understand what is happening or why, so I'm hoping also to _learn_ more here :) (2/2)

Comment: Could you respond to my specific question about `ArgTypes[K]`?  If I remove that from your "attempt N" I get [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKOVzW) where now you have, at most, 4 type parameters, and it seems to display the same issue.  Can you change to something like that?  If not, why not?

Comment: Assuming the previous comment is an adequate [mre] for this (and if so, you should maybe [edit] the question to include it): If you are willing to manually annotate the callback parameter types everywhere, then you can do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2z4jw).  But a builder or a bag of calls to `args()` is going to be much better.

Comment: Finally, for SO it helps a lot if a post [asks a single primary question and not a set of questions](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741/511366) (unless one is really called out as the main question).  You are asking "Is it possible to do this or should I give up? If so, how?" (I consider that one question) and "Is there a reference to show how to 'step through' Typescript's behavior to understand it better?"  Which one of those two are you really looking for here? I understand it would be nice to have both, but if you get two answer posts that answer each one respectively, which one is correct?

Comment: Examining what you did, I don't see any reason not to do it that way, other than I didn't understand when and where I could do so. I'll happily edit it in. I'll also remove the other question. I'm mostly looking for "is this possible? how?"; the question about "how can I figure this out myself next time" is mostly secondary :)

Comment: I'd definitely rather change the user-facing interface (e.g. by the builder pattern) than force the user to annotate the types, so that's where I'm leaning.

Comment: All right, I'll write an answer here when I get a chance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying problem here is that TypeScript has a limited ability to simultaneously infer [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters and [contextually type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) function parameters.  The inference algorithm is a set of reasonable heuristics that works in a lot of common use cases, but it is not a *full [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) algorithm* guaranteed to assign the proper types to all generic type arguments and all unannotated values, as proposed (but not yet or possibly ever implemented) in [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134).

So generic type parameters can be inferred:

```
declare function foo<T>(x: (n: number) => T): T
foo((n: number) => ({ a: n })) // T inferred as {a: number}
```

and unannotated function parameters can be inferred:

```
declare function bar(f: (x: { a: number }) => void): void;
bar(x => x.a.toFixed(1)) // x inferred as {a: number}
```

and there is *some* ability to do both at once, especially if you are asking to infer from multiple function arguments and the flow of inference goes from left to right:

```
declare function baz<T>(x: (n: number) => T, f: (x: T) => void): void;
baz((n) => ({ a: n }), x => x.a.toFixed(1))
// n inferred as number, T inferred as {a: number}, x inferred as {a: number}
```

But there are cases where this doesn't work.  Before TypeScript 4.7, the following variant where you have a single function argument would fail to infer as desired:

```
declare function qux<T>(arg: { x: (n: number) => T, f: (x: T) => void }): void;
qux({ x: (n) => ({ a: n }), f: x => x.a.toFixed(1) })
// TS 4.6, n inferred as number, T failed to infer, x failed to infer
// TS 4.7, n inferred as number, T inferred as {a: number}, x inferred as {a: number}
```

This was fixed [in TypeScript 4.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#improved-function-inference-in-objects-and-methods) with [microsoft/TypeScript#48538](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48538).  But it's still far from a perfect algorithm.

For example, this sort of inference breaks down when combined with [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).  Simple inference from a mapped type looks like this:

```
declare function frm<T>(obj: { [K in keyof T]: (n: number) => T[K] }): void;
frm({ p: n => ({ a: n }) });
// T inferred as {p: {a: number}}
```

But try to combine that with simultaneous contextual inference of function parameters, and it fails:

```
declare function doa<T>(
    obj: { [K in keyof T]: { x: (n: number) => T[K], f: (x: T[K]) => void } }
): void;
doa({ p: { x: (n) => ({ a: n }), f: x => x.a.toFixed(1) } });
// TS 4.8, T failed to infer
doa<{ p: { a: number } }>(
  { p: { x: (n) => ({ a: n }), f: x => x.a.toFixed(1) } }); // okay
```

So, unfortunately, if the relationship you're trying to express with your types involves a lot of complicated inference paths involving contextual typing, it's probably going to fail.

---

Your example code is trying to do inference from mapped types and callback parameter inference at the same time, so it fails.  Well, a call signature like

```
function ops<T extends { [key: string]: any }, O extends Ops<T>>(spec: O): O {
    return spec;
}
```

would never work, because [generic constraints do not serve as inference sites](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71865965/2887218); see [microsoft/TypeScript#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234).  The compiler cannot infer `T` from the fact that `O extends Ops<T>`.  We need to change it to something like

```
function ops<T>(spec: Ops<T>): Ops<T> { // infer from mapped type
    return spec;
}
```

then we *can* get inference... although he error messages are a bit weird because you replace the type with `never` in `InferArgs`:

```
const okay = ops({
    one: { // okay
        lhs: {
            type: 'string',
            from: (v: string) => String(v)
        },
        rhs: {
            type: 'number',
            from: (v: number) => v.toString()
        },
        compare: (lhs: string, rhs: string) => lhs !== rhs
    }, two: { // error!
        lhs: {
            type: 'string',
            from: (v: string) => String(v)
        },
        rhs: {
            type: 'number',
            from: (v: string) => v.toString()
        },
        compare: (lhs: string, rhs: string) => lhs !== rhs
    },
    three: { // error!
        lhs: {
            type: 'string',
            from: (v: string) => String(v)
        },
        rhs: {
            type: 'number',
            from: (v: number) => v.toString()
        },
        compare: (lhs: number, rhs: string) => lhs !== rhs
    },
    four: { // error
        lhs: {
            type: 'string',
            from: (v: string) => String(v)
        },
        rhs: {
            type: 'number',
            from: (v: number) => v.toString()
        },
        compere: (lhs: string, rhs: string) => lhs !== rhs,
    }
})
```

I think I'd probably try to make it so that failures are replaced with "the right" type instead of `never`, which might look like

```
function ops<T>(ops:
    T & { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends {
        lhs: { type: infer KL extends keyof ArgTypes, from: (arg: any) => infer RL },
        rhs: { type: infer KR extends keyof ArgTypes, from: (arg: any) => infer RR }
    } ? Args<KL, KR, RL, RR> : Args<keyof ArgTypes, keyof ArgTypes, unknown, unknown> }
): T { return ops };
```

which results in this, with slightly better error placement:

```
const okay = ops({
    one: { // okay
        lhs: {
            type: 'string',
            from: (v: string) => String(v)
        },
        rhs: {
            type: 'number',
            from: (v: number) => v.toString()
        },
        compare: (lhs: string, rhs: string) => lhs !== rhs
    }, two: {
        lhs: {
            type: 'string',
            from: (v: string) => String(v)
        },
        rhs: {
            type: 'number',
            from: (v: string) => v.toString() // error, wrong v
        },
        compare: (lhs: string, rhs: string) => lhs !== rhs
    },
    three: {
        lhs: {
            type: 'string',
            from: (v: string) => String(v)
        },
        rhs: {
            type: 'number',
            from: (v: number) => v.toString()
        },
        compare: (lhs: number, rhs: string) => lhs !== rhs // error, wrong lhs
    },
    four: { // error. missing compare
        lhs: {
            type: 'string',
            from: (v: string) => String(v)
        },
        rhs: {
            type: 'number',
            from: (v: number) => v.toString()
        },
        compere: (lhs: string, rhs: string) => lhs !== rhs,
    }
})
```

And that's about the best I can do, if you need to have a single object literal with all the properties inline, all at once.

---

Assuming this isn't already-existing code that you're giving types to, though, you don't need to go this route.  As you mentioned, you could use a builder pattern or the like to let users build up their object in stages, where each stage requires just a bit of inference to succeed, like using `args()` multiple times.  For example:

```
class BuildOps<T extends Record<keyof T, Args<any, any, any, any>>> {
    constructor(public ops: T) { }
    add<K extends PropertyKey, KL extends keyof ArgTypes,
        KR extends keyof ArgTypes, RL, RR>(
            key: K,
            args: Args<KL, KR, RL, RR>
        ): BuildOps<T & Record<K, Args<KL, KR, RL, RR>>> {
        return new BuildOps({ ...this.ops, [key]: args } as any);
    }
    build(): { [K in keyof T]: T[K] } {
        return this.ops;
    }
    static emptyBuilder: BuildOps<{}> = new BuildOps({})
    static add = BuildOps.emptyBuilder.add.bind(BuildOps.emptyBuilder);
}
```

Which could be used like:

```
const myOps = BuildOps.add("one", {
    lhs: { type: 'string', from: v => String(v) },
    rhs: { type: 'number', from: v => v.toFixed(2) },
    compare: (lhs, rhs) => lhs !== rhs
}).add("two", {
    lhs: { type: 'number', from: v => v > 3 },
    rhs: { type: 'boolean', from: v => v ? 0 : 1 },
    compare(l, r) { return (l ? 0 : 1) === r }
}).build();
/* const myOps: {
    one: Args<"string", "number", string, string>;
    two: Args<"number", "boolean", boolean, 1 | 0>;
} */
```

That works with the capabilities of the inference algorithm instead of against it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#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-HKYKabFyBtEoyUjxqGAORwlAArXkAbQA0tMkGgIJgOHRdABdfmLKz-QQNztS6oVWXEOhlxUwJzFVVAo1qMdESZYrPO-HTnNE5x5tYF+mMYu7EgcEAcz7GSs13BIBtNlttjuCbs3k7mKl91oD+udjUPAyDhKNQuC4nxvDUS6kKeU68m+fytHO4TqqKoLap0upQgaYwga4kErpG7QABxugGnrehwvqfCeZ72JugIfqoOFiLRsH8iq9HcMCKFguhkL6jCRqFLUExeBwGCYAQKwsJgMDIAAgtQXKCDJ0BaLgny0JqTBoMAHAAO7AJBSh8F6IBnMZHCmYZnxQCw1C+DySC2fZwBcpBgq9qo9TOPUeC+CwqgBogSAKVy-CNhA4gBcAJAhA+7YhYpymyVAdwAEo6PgxjSbJ0j1pBE4cGAWTctIoXJdAgGtGleArP5gUIPJilQOFAAySCRdFsXNq2CXlSpqVIPWaUdVFEAxXFvUdv1KXpa16UZepxgUAAFlAZWKW1c3CDcGlrRtYXDQtO2fPARVwLQWSretSBpfNSDUPtt1pf8FlWd5BCgJAsCNUgAASYBgOpnw5cgACSjqhS1IhaBexBYp143dVD-DJkgrX1ncaOtWlWOOrdmO+s9OgAPxw0QKMY3cOPpYTaWLfIEAlF5MREKDqAwNDOiaEtxjEHevg9Y+XYAT+o1dSEEPIij36dqTuiDkgjPM9Qnw+azDLJLsHCcxysDkNIKC6yIVRG1zvN8w9EAsAw1DcPr8CQbuSBncAtlIGJWBqTrUB2OTHvABAvKTJ7EmW5b105P74dIKD0gAOTOQ58e7THMeFcVMglNISeuf8Zp2Q5oglHCafEM4qdlw9T1ZVX2UqQngop9H4cZ1k2cMUKOglLqBcuVyoil1XFct0QZ1gBdQcyJHTmF65dyPTdudcv811IAAhJoPOL-7Fex3pHDB14AQcNQ6+j0gM+13XbMN0gidz1yzc3+O1BFe3OeP-nj-F0PZcj3XReUcX631yvfJulcX5tyzp-fuEpe4-z-mnABVdx6Tyuk9ZeC9MFf1aGvTe281q70gXzFgK1aBT3sJME+Z8L5XwvvXMBD9+7PxAdA4usCHLf37r-C+KCy5AItjfOO4CiSsKgW-TOHDO7wJ6H3IuSCY78LTmghIGCbqJkEcvVea0N5b2rlAYh-teC2yPh1FEp86E1wYcQERzDk4kLruwju2jWjyNcrwuuyiY6COvsIu+8cIE2KIM4zyXdSgIJ4Yo8O3jw5oNUFPUQM8sEGM4XnPBuiCEGMceXNWcJJIEEPFrbgPsKyc0kJ8LEAAyG8AtuDxSfC+WW4skb4n9lfWOd80b1naojCaQs+pJQGhqSRJVFLSDMpgf4aM7ouByUQXxnSwHdJGn07qDTEpKWGaWd+MhSoOGAFM1oMyRrRGMM4JAJNNktR6XcI6t17r0x0AdFqGyZrQDuG8oZs0kDaV0gZO4fz9LAB0NEKoWJ7C0BtnbD2nMXC+Vdu7UiFAHLe05n7S8gczGh3adYuudjl7iLTqE2ecC3E-xLkYnxeKq52KCU40ZMCZHPEiQoqlcTzpqOnjg-u2Cl64OKPg-RO9zl3BYAfYB4d6H4oCYS+ZfMSWuOKO4gelKlHyt8RfOlYj5XGEVQK7urKPEeGPhYv0SA9Jv1cqUdlltVGXW5fy3lqTSVcIySELJIry4kLIRQyVEcaVlwJY-Il6dGXSKVToFVniYkasDWnbVSxQ2t3DR3QUsiODRuiUQWJY9OUOqSU9TRPK3WCsycK3R1CzV3EtVwLkl8iGis+CY6gZiaHtCQGANgUAoCovtRAXFN0-Ex2DSw3Vr9dkRoNUgaNarY3+01TKph9Kq4kvTSyuRiDbV83iQW5Jj8+VpJXu6vRhDUpq1qvkzw9VqBBSalyG5vSxr9K+Vsn5w0Wkvqmpsiqg07rHWBvEHtSAABCDBPQkDNkIT93U0rkFPiQfgGyRQo0mXcNDBzMDocOcIXDQjEV2QYKwU+ogYAMCUCi+AsKbpPHsGc4gIASCIYis+7qAAFN+slqDSXrK2O5T6JYDOmt8j5-sP1rMmsLd5f7HkZVEBfB8eVx1EG5DdFGtyhq4wecdf2VQwMQag9U268HqDMbuOp+69z-3Ezw8O4gULbbcEDnpUD4GKCQfRfYdo3myHdvaD7O4tYHwvlUyBCkkzFwXuMEoNzwwqj2DqUJkWCsxYXLsws62jnY4rT8z7J2NkWAgHYFRiAE9pL6fc6oaQFWPMtRwM4bm4QIAuZq2bOwxpjC2SK2wKjjGgg81a5zdopWYDldi6oToTH2hKF8MMQbUBhtlcwDVy4H08AEc7ZgM2al5uTeGAAIi4BAfbdw-EdNHQ4nZmcSjkp4SXOZe0h1LKnoEnVV3pQbr1NCUQAAmI0JD+3qL5Toj1FbDGuD26Ifb4qOAnaEedgJED3ulGeEgHQABmB7xhFl2LehAMyKdkc3eKDdq5AAGJWSARhY+IP2pJC8NCQsyzCpJlykAU+kNhLe29QIQ5ixBwe9R3AACoXZcHdmALb5ShFHZefwfby84f7cFHDlJy9hCQRh3L5XRIld47MnD-XwA7jU4AD7s417VJAwv3B4CAA)

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer and explanation :) It's tricky when I don't understand a thing fully to know the difference between "I'm doing it wrong" and "it's not doable", especially with the lack of direct feedback. Marking as the answer, and gonna just go with the builder pattern.

Comment: Just to follow up: after working on this for a few days, it was clear that my abstractions didn't fit with what I actually needed, but I was able to adapt your example to build something that I think fits more cleanly: https://tsplay.dev/mArQQW

The main thing is that the _parser_ level has syntax support for creating sets, for example. I want the guarantee within a context that both sides are of the same type, but I need to be able to define operations like "in set". So, I lifted the base type higher and made a way for an operator to "ask" for a set of that  base type, for example :)